# How do I fix the size of a UITextView under a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uitextview

Having a very strange behavior problem with a UITextView.

In IB Storyboard I dropped a View Controller. Then dropped a UITextView on top. Then resized the UITextView to fit, made an IBOutlet for it and saved.

I'm pushing the UIViewController on to a UINavigationController via a segue.

The problem is that the UITextView wants to consume the entire screen, minus the navigation bar. In IB, the UITextView is supposed be: x:20, y:83, w:280, h:164, not the whole screen.

Help?

Update:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 83, 280, 164); // does nothing...
}
```

Putting the UITextView in a UIView had no change. Springs and Struts removed.

Comment: seems like autoResizingMask isn't set correctly on UITextView.  Should be set UIViewAutoresizingNone?  Check those springs/struts in IB

Comment: first off you should use property accessors to access properties on an object. self.myTextView.frame but you should put a breakpoint on that line and check what myTextView is. Is the connection active. or does myTextView == nil

Comment: also, make sure that your Text view is not connected to the view property of the View controller. other than that. Im out of ideas.

Comment: I must have mistakenly CTRL-dragged it and made the Controller a delegate. Removed the link in IB, problem solved. Thanks for the sanity checks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my UIViewController was connected as a delegate of the UITextView in Interface Builder. Removing this made the UITextView resizeable.

Answer (score 0):

transition a UIView into the space. and not a UITextView. put the UITextView inside the UIView and it will have its regular space. Also all the "Springs and Struts" will work within that view as well.

You may consider putting that UITextView into a UIViewController (which will ultimately have a UIView in it)

Another thing to look at is:

Make sure your UITextView is not connected to the View property of the Controller. And check to see that your code setting the frame uses an instantiated version of UITextView. but a breakpoint and check the value of myTextView. see if it is nil. maybe the connection is not made. Perhaps it is not loading your custom class. or perhaps its connecting itself to another outlet which destroys it and puts something else in its place.

Comment: Putting the UITextView in a UIView had no change. Springs and Struts removed.